# The Uniqueness of an artifactId in maven

Tags: java, maven

- Let's say that there are 2 maven artifacts (local) with the same
  groupId but with a different artifactId.
- The different artifactId should make each maven artifact unique.
- However, if both of the unique artifacts each have a class with that share the same name. that class will not be unique because when it is imported to java it will use the groupId.className format. and the neither groupId nor the className are unique (in the discussed case).
- This will result in an issue of ambiguity as to determining which class to use.
- Upon testing it seems that the dependency declared first in the pom.xml file will be used.

**The Question Are**

1. **What is the best practice solve/avoid this issue?**
2. **Why does maven's artifactId coordinate contribute to the uniqueness of a maven artifact within the repository but not inside the java code?**

Example Code:
 [Maven - Same Class Name Same GroupId Different ArtifactId](https://bitbucket.org/lesu/maven-same-class-name-same-groupid-different-artifactid)

- Project1 is the first artifact.
- Project2 is the second artifact.
- "Projects User" is the artifact/project that will depend on both Project1 & Project2.
- Project1 & Project2 both have a class named `Utilities`.
- The class `Utilities` have a static method `public static String getDescription()` that returns a `string` containing the current project's artifact coordinates as well as the project name.
- `Utilities.getDescription()` resulting `String` is called to see if an error will occur somewhere, and to see how it will be resolved.
- The output depends on which dependency was declared first in the pom.xml file of the "Projects User" artifact.

**Edited : Follow up Question**

- **Is there an archetype that will create the java package using both the artifactId and groupId instead of having to do it manually every
  time?**

Comment: Class name has nothing to do with the artefact or groupId

Comment: Java classes are accessed like `com.mypackage.MyClass` not `groupId.MyClass`. I guess, you have two artifacts which has same packages and the same class.

Comment: The package name should be unique. You should for example use the domain you control or some kind of unique nickname or whatever and then the project name.

Comment: @jens 
That is a very important clarification that i did not know. I assumed that they should be the same, and i apparently was wrong, ty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the best practice solve/avoid this issue?

We include the groupId and artifactId as the base package in the module. This way it is not possible to have the same class in two modules as the packages would be different.

e.g.

```
<groupId>net.openhft</groupId>
<artifactId>chronicle-bytes</artifactId>
```

has everything under the package

```
package net.openhft.chronicle.bytes;
```

Also if you know the package of a class you know which JAR it must be in.

if you have a class two JARs need, I suggest creating a common module, they both depend on.

Note: it is general practice to use your company domain name (and notional division as well) as the base of your package. Maven recommend using your domain name as you groupId and if you release to Maven Central this is now a requirement. The above strategy supports both recommendations.

> Why does maven's artifactId coordinate contribute to the uniqueness of a maven artifact within the repository but not inside the java code?

Maven doesn't take any notice of the contents of the JAR.

Comment: I would also add information, that Maven suggests using your domain as groupId

Answer (score 1):

@Peter following your lead on suggesting best practices to avoid this issue.

1. Group Id : It is required to uniquely identify your project. Revese of your domain name ex : 
   com.github.dibyaranjan
2. artifactId is the name of the jar without version.

To distinguish two classes from different JARs, Create package as groupId.artifactId.

For Example, I would create a project TestDummy, I want the name of the JAR to be TestDummy-1.1, then my package would look like.

`com.github.dibyaranjan.testdummy`

The class would look like - `com.github.dibyaranjan.testdummy.MyClass`

For reference visit : https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-naming-conventions.html